# Html+PhP Submit button not working

Tags: php, html

So, i'm new here as well new to html, i'm reading some sites(for some hours now) and as far as i can tell my code should work, but it dosen't...
I just want to click a button and recieve it's name as echo. But when I click noting happen.
Any good soul to help out? :P

```
<head>
    <title>Index</title>

</head>

<body>
    <div>

        <input type="submit" name="insert" value="insert" >
        <input type="submit" name="select" value="select" >


    </div>

    <?php

        if (isset( $_GET['insert'])) {
            echo "insert";
        }
        if ( isset( $_GET['select'] ) ) {
            echo "select";
        }
    ?>

</body>
```

Comment: Check my answer. Your body is closed after php tags.

Answer (score 1):

submit button works with form because only form can be submit so  u can try with  :

```
<form method="get" name="frm">

<input type="submit" name="select" value="select" >

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

please insert your div into a form like

```
<head>
    <title>Index</title> 
</head> 

<body>
    <form  method="get" action="">
        <div>

            <input type="submit" name="insert" value="insert" >
            <input type="submit" name="select" value="select" >


        </div>
    </form>
        <?php

            if (isset( $_GET['insert'])) {
                echo "insert";
            }
            if ( isset( $_GET['select'] ) ) {
                echo "select";
            }
        ?>

    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add form tags like this

```
<form>

<input type="submit" name="insert" value="insert" >
<input type="submit" name="select" value="select" >

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write the form tag or use below code on top right of the page

```
if(isset($_POST['insert'])){
...
}

 if(isset($_POST['select'])){
 ...
 }
```

Comment: Not necessary to send form via POST. he used GET so don't force him to use POST method.

Answer (score 0):

Check This

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Index</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <form method="GET" action="#">
        <input type="submit" name="insert" value="insert" >
        <input type="submit" name="select" value="select" >
        </from>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
    <?php

        if (isset( $_GET['insert'])) {
            echo "insert";
           }
        if ( isset( $_GET['select'] ) ) {
            echo "select";
           }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please first Define method in form.

```
<form method="GET" action="#">
<input type="submit" name="insert" value="insert" >
<input type="submit" name="select" value="select" >
</form>
```

Comment: Replace from with form. and always format you code. And always write your description outside your code.  PHP form default method is GET.  So no need to define it. But for good practice we should add method attribute.